# How to apply 3D-LUT to Bitmap using NDK, without using OpenCV

Tags: android, android-ndk

I am a beginner in NDK and I want to traverse a Bitmap in NDK to look up a LUT table and apply LUT filter. However, I am not clear about the mapping rules of the LUT.

its my cpp code

```cpp
//
// Created by PengHaiChen on 2023/6/20.
//

#include "lutFilterImage.h"
#include <jni.h>
#include <android/bitmap.h>

jobject createBitmap(JNIEnv *pEnv, int width, int height);

jobject getLutFilterImage(JNIEnv *pEnv, jobject thiz, jobject bitmap, jobject lut_bitmap) {
    AndroidBitmapInfo bitmapInfo;
    if (AndroidBitmap_getInfo(pEnv, bitmap, &bitmapInfo) < 0) {
        return nullptr;
    }

    if (bitmapInfo.format != ANDROID_BITMAP_FORMAT_RGBA_8888) {
        return nullptr;
    }

    uint32_t *srcPixels;
    if (AndroidBitmap_lockPixels(pEnv, bitmap, (void **) &srcPixels) < 0) {
        return nullptr;
    }

    AndroidBitmapInfo lutBitmapInfo;
    if (AndroidBitmap_getInfo(pEnv, lut_bitmap, &lutBitmapInfo) < 0) {
        return nullptr;
    }

    if (lutBitmapInfo.format != ANDROID_BITMAP_FORMAT_RGBA_8888) {
        return nullptr;
    }

    uint32_t *lutPixels;
    if (AndroidBitmap_lockPixels(pEnv, lut_bitmap, (void **) &lutPixels) < 0) {
        return nullptr;
    }

    jobject newBitmap = createBitmap(pEnv, (int)bitmapInfo.width, (int)bitmapInfo.height);

    uint32_t *dstPixels;
    if (AndroidBitmap_lockPixels(pEnv, newBitmap, (void **) &dstPixels) < 0) {
        return nullptr;
    }

    for (int y = 0; y < bitmapInfo.height; y++) {
        for (int x = 0; x < bitmapInfo.width; x++) {
            uint32_t srcPixel = srcPixels[y * bitmapInfo.width + x];

            uint8_t srcR = (srcPixel >> 16) & 0xff;
            uint8_t srcG = (srcPixel >> 8) & 0xff;
            uint8_t srcB = srcPixel & 0xff;


            uint32_t dstPixel =
                    (srcPixel & 0xff000000) | (srcR << 16) | (srcG << 8) | srcB;
            dstPixels[y * bitmapInfo.width + x] = dstPixel;
        }
    }

    AndroidBitmap_unlockPixels(pEnv, bitmap);
    AndroidBitmap_unlockPixels(pEnv, lut_bitmap);
    AndroidBitmap_unlockPixels(pEnv, newBitmap);

    return newBitmap;
}

jobject createBitmap(JNIEnv *pEnv, int width, int height) {
    jclass bitmapClass = pEnv->FindClass("android/graphics/Bitmap");
    if (bitmapClass == nullptr) {
        return nullptr;
    }

    jclass bitmapConfigClass = pEnv->FindClass("android/graphics/Bitmap$Config");
    if (bitmapConfigClass == nullptr) {
        return nullptr;
    }

    jfieldID argb8888Field = pEnv->GetStaticFieldID(bitmapConfigClass, "ARGB_8888",
                                                    "Landroid/graphics/Bitmap$Config;");
    if (argb8888Field == nullptr) {
        return nullptr;
    }
    jobject argb8888 = pEnv->GetStaticObjectField(bitmapConfigClass, argb8888Field);

    jmethodID createBitmapMethod = pEnv->GetStaticMethodID(bitmapClass, "createBitmap",
                                                           "(IILandroid/graphics/Bitmap$Config;)Landroid/graphics/Bitmap;");
    if (createBitmapMethod == nullptr) {
        return nullptr;
    }

    return pEnv->CallStaticObjectMethod(bitmapClass, createBitmapMethod, width, height, argb8888);
}
```

its my lut image

[image]

I have left out the logic for LUT mapping and I do not know how to proceed. I would be grateful if you could help me with this.